# Check statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I've the following code:

```
def update_for_transport_document
    # => DESCRIPTION:
    # => Utilizzata nelle form di associazione di un warehouse ad una bolla
    @wh_errors = Hash.new

    if request.path.include? "ingress_transport_document"
        session[:user_role] != "administrator" ?
            @itd = IngressTransportDocument.filtered_by_registry(session[:registry_id]).find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id]) :
            @itd = IngressTransportDocument.find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id])
            @all_itd = IngressTransportDocument.all
            logger.debug { "INGRESS_TRANSPORT_DOCUMENT_ID: #{@itd.id} " }
           @warehouse = Warehouse.find(params[:warehouse][:id])

           #check_warehouse_in_td(@all_itd,@warehouse)
          @all_itd.each do |td|
            td.warehouses.each do |whs|
                logger.debug {"TD WAREHOUSES:#{whs.id} && #{@warehouse.id}"}
                    if whs.id == @warehouse.id
                     @ok = 'ciccia'
                     break
                   break
              end               
       end
       end
       logger.debug {"OK:#{@ok} "}
        if @ok != 'ciccia'  
  @itd.warehouses << @warehouse

           else
            logger.debug{"NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"}
           end  
              respond_to do |format|   
         format.html { redirect_to(@itd) }
            format.xml  { head :ok }
            end



    else 

        session[:user_role] != "administrator" ?
            @etd = EgressTransportDocument.filtered_by_registry(session[:registry_id]).find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id]) :
            @etd = EgressTransportDocument.find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id])
            logger.debug { "TEST" }
            logger.debug { "EGRESS_TRANSPORT_DOCUMENT_ID: #{@etd.id}" }
               @warehouse = Warehouse.find(params[:warehouse][:id])
           logger.debug { "WAREHOUSE_ID: #{@warehouse.id}" }
    @etd.warehouses << @warehouse
             respond_to do |format|
               format.html { redirect_to(@etd) }
               format.xml  { head :ok } 
          end
      end
```

end

and I'd want that `@warehouse` can be append to `@itd(@etd).warehouses` only if the same warehouse is not present in others `ingress(egress)transport` documents.

My issue is that using this code any warehouse can be append to `@itd(@etd).warehouses` both if warehouse is present in another transport document neither if it's a new one not associated to any `itd/etd`.

Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to find bug in your code.

I will not try to guess which single line makes errors, instead I will give you few hints:

There is general rule in Rails environment `fat models - skinny controllers`. For your code it means: leave only the minimum over code generated by scaffolding. All business logic move into models. You may ask why: there are few reasons: you can reuse your code, it's much easier to make unit test against model than controller.

I would really encourage you to try build unit test for logic in your model. It is much efficient than debugging. However debugger is still powerfull tool, I use debugger from Rubymine. Debugger gives you possibility to inspect all variables state in line-by-line application execution.

One thing in your code: overuse of `?` operator

```
session[:user_role] != "administrator" ?
        @itd = IngressTransportDocument.filtered_by_registry(session[:registry_id]).find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id]) :
        @itd = IngressTransportDocument.find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id])
```

Is less readable than:

```
if session[:user_role] != "administrator" then
    @itd = IngressTransportDocument.filtered_by_registry(session[:registry_id]).find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id]) 
else
    @itd = IngressTransportDocument.find(params[:warehouse][:ingress_transport_document_id])
end if
```